# Postgres: Selecting a 24 hour window for multiple dates and picking the initial date as start date

Tags: postgresql, date

I'm trying to select 24 hour chunks of data for a list of days and retain the start date. It's easier to describe with a table so I'll do that:

Original Table

```
ID      localminute          Usage
1   01-01-2013 00:00:00-05    3
.
.
1   12-31-2013 00:00:00-05    4
2
.
.
```

Let's say the dates I'm interested in are February 1st and February 12th. What I want then is the aggregate usage from 8 AM on February 1st to 07:59 AM on February 2nd and likewise 8 AM February 12th to 7:59 AM February 13th.

This will be for each individual person so my output will be:

```
ID       Eventday      Total
 1      02-01-2013      78
 1      02-01-2013      89
 2      02-13-2013      94
 2      02-13-2013      67
 .
 .
```

My problem here is adding the date I start counting on the item to event day i.e February 1st in case 1 and February 13th in the second case I'm not sure how to do that because of the overlapping days. My simple query for getting the aggregate minus the date is below:

```
create table aggregates as
select id, sum(usage) as total
from source_table
where localminute between '02-01-2013 08:00' AND '02-02-2013 07:59'
group by dataid

union  

same as above for February 13th.
```

If I select the date column and add the date column as it is in the group by statement, I can't control the date item as it randomly comes as 02-01-2013 or 02-02-2013 depending on the situation.

Is there a way to manually input the day into the column for each iteration or some other workaround by storing my days in a list etc.?

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like what you want is making everything that happens before 8am count towards the previous day. In this case, you can offset the timestamp by 8 hours, truncate on the day, and use it for grouping.

```
SELECT id, date_trunc('day', localminute - '8 hours'::interval)::date,
       SUM(usage)
FROM source_table
GROUP BY id, date_trunc('day', localminute - '8 hours'::interval)
```

If you're only interested in the data between `01 Feb 2013 08:00` and `13 Feb 2013 08:00`, you can add `WHERE localminute >= '01 Feb 2013 08:00'::timestamptz AND localminute < '13 Feb 2013 08:00'::timestamptz` (before `GROUP BY`).

I would avoid `'02-02-2013 07:59'` and go for a strict inequality on `'02-13-2013 08:00'`, to be able to catch entries occuring during that last minute ([`BETWEEN` includes the end of the range](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-comparison.html)). Alternatively, if you're using a sufficiently recent version of PostgreSQL, you could use a [range type](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/rangetypes.html), although for something reasonably short like this, the two inequality (as above) seem reasonable.

Comment: Perfect, Thanks Bruno! 

I appreciate the tip about the strict inequality, I see that I miss out on one entry there. Thanks again!

I would upvote but I don't have enough credits just yet

Answer (score 0):

I'd do something like:

```
select id, sum(usage) as total,
       date_trunc('day', localminute - dayoffset)::date
from source_table
where localminute between (startday + dayoffset)
                      and (startday + dayoffset + '1 day')
group by id, date_trunc('day', localminute - dayoffset)::date
```

where startday would be the date '2015-02-01', and dayoffset would be the interval '8 hours'.

Comment: Hi Jay, thanks for your comment. 

I tried out what you've said above but it still doesn't control for the day. I still get both '01-02-2015' and '02-02-2015' in my date columns. I need for it to all be '01-02-2015'. I'll update my code with yours in the answer above.